# Checking if a duplicate record is actually a duplicate - Doing Dupe check then finding deeper data shows it is not a dupe

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have an issue which is the following:
I am running a report each days which shows me the duplicate records in a table. In reality these "Records" have a number of layers, so each record has a "description record"

So, I'm doing a check on the Records table where the record has a certain status and the count is >1
To do this I am using a Stored Procedure which creates a table with all Records called #AllRecords and a table with only duplicates so where  COUNT(*) > 1 called #AllDuplicates

I'm then doing a join between these tables where the status is "Yes" and finding the duplicates.

This is where I am seeing the issue,  its flagging 2 records as a duplicate when actually they have the same "Ref" but different "Desc" therefore it is not a duplicate.

This is how they relate to eachother:
Records Table contains the Ref
RecordsDesc Table contains the Ref and Desc
Desc Table contains the Desc

Is there anyway to incorporate the Desc into the check and compare if against the records to show if the record is actually a duplicate or not?

Thanks.

Comment: Please update your question to show your table structure and provide sample data that illustrates why the data is considered a duplicate at a high level but not at a lower level

Comment: @NickW Please find an updated post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74715563/check-for-a-duplicate-where-all-columns-in-one-view-are-identical-amongst-two-re